# How to add optional React components inside another React component via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the best approach for adding *optional* components inside a component?

I have one like this:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.Node,
  title?: string,
  /**May add any component next to the header. Should be inside a fragment. */
  headerComponents?: React.Node,
  className?: string,
}

export const Content = ({ children, className, title, headerComponents }: Props) => (
  <div className={`page-content ${className}`}>
     <div className='page-content-header'>
       {
         title && (
           <h2 className='content-title'>{title}</h2>
         )
       }
       {
         headerComponents && (
           <div className='page-header-right'> {headerComponents} </div>
         )
       }
     </div>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

The `headerComponent` acts as a prop that can receive another component, like this:

```
<Page.Content
  headerComponents={
    <>
      <Button>First</Button>
      <Button>Second</Button>
    </>
  }
  title='Example title'
>
  <div>Example text</div>
</Page.Content>
```

And it works. But I'm wondering if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

This approach looks fine to me. It is readable and intuitive to pass props to the component, followed by conditionally rendering the optional components based on the values of the props.